# Error while using WriteToBigquery in python for Dataflow pipeline. Unicode object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python, json, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

My sample data is in json format and looks like:

```
{
  "metadata": {
    "action": "insert",
    "type": "export",
    "version": 1,
    "timestamp": "2018-11-23T09:17:59.048-08:00"
  },
  "data": {
    "attr1": 61,
    "day": "2018-11-22",
    "pin": "2C49956",
    "CDP": 0,
    "DP": 0,
    "VD": 0,
    "seo": 0,
    "dir": 0,
    "other": 0,
    "at": 0
  }
}
```

This is in a flat file and the objective is to run a dataflow pipeline in batch mode to insert the data into bigquery table. In one of the transformations where I want to take timestamp from the metadata and add it as a key value pair in the data section, I am getting the error from dataflow saying 'unicode object has no attribute 'items'.

The code looks as below:

```
import collections
import json
import argparse
import logging
from datetime import datetime
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions, GoogleCloudOptions, StandardOptions, SetupOptions, \
    WorkerOptions
from apache_beam.io.gcp import bigquery


# Creating options object
def create_options(argv):
    # pipeline options
    options = PipelineOptions()
    google_cloud_options = options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions)
    google_cloud_options.project = 'something'
    google_cloud_options.job_name = datetime.now().strftime('somename')
    google_cloud_options.staging_location = 'some_loc'
    google_cloud_options.temp_location = 'another_loc'
    options.view_as(StandardOptions).runner = 'DirectRunner'
    options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True
    options.view_as(WorkerOptions).machine_type = 'n1-standard-1'
    return options

    class PrepareData(beam.DoFn):
        """
        ParDo function to create a dictionary of data for downstream consumption
        """

        def process(self, element):
            data = json.loads(element)
            modified_data = {"action": data["metadata"]["action"], "timestamp": data["metadata"]["timestamp"], "data": data}
            return [modified_data]


    class FilterInserts(beam.DoFn):
        """
        Filter data for inserts
        """

        def process(self, element):
            if element["action"] == "insert":
                element['data']['data']['timestamp'] = element['timestamp']
                # for dict in element["data"]["data"]:
                #     dict["timestamp"] = element["timestamp"]
                return element["data"]["data"]


    def run_pipe(options, argv):
        """
        Creating pipelines
        """
        p = beam.Pipeline(options=options)

        main_pipe =p | 'PREPARE_DATA' >> beam.io.ReadFromText('/home/Downloads/sample_1') | beam.ParDo(PrepareData())

        """ Separating pipes for various actions """
        insert_pipe= main_pipe | beam.ParDo(FilterInserts())

        """
        Inserts--> sinking to BQ
        """
        insert_pipe | 'INSERT' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            project='some-data-warehouse',
            dataset='sample_data',
            table='sample',
            write_disposition='WRITE_APPEND',
            create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED')


        p.run()


    def main():
        """
        Main function to drive the run
        :return: errors if any
        """
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        args = parser.parse_args()
        try:
            # create options
            opt = create_options(argv=args)
            # run pipeline
            run_pipe(opt, argv=args)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error('Pipeline failed with error : %s', e)
            raise Exception('Pipeline failed with error : %s', e)


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

I am running this on direct runner to test on local but i get the same error even if i change the runner to dataflow-runner.
The error message is:

```
Exception: ('Pipeline failed with error : %s', AttributeError(u"'unicode' object has no attribute 'items' [while running 'INSERT/WriteToBigQuery']",))
```

Can anyone help me figure out what's going wrong and how i can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

By using the following table's `schema` (You can modify it according to your necessities):

```
schema = 'VD:INTEGER,pin:STRING,timestamp:STRING,other:INTEGER,CDP:INTEGER,dir:INTEGER,attr1:INTEGER,seo:INTEGER,day:STRING,DP:INTEGER,at:INTEGER'
```

Try the following on your `FilterInserts` class:

```
class FilterInserts(beam.DoFn):
    """
    Filter data for inserts
    """

    def process(self, element):
        if element["action"] == "insert":
            element['data']['data']['timestamp'] = element['timestamp']

            return [{
            'VD': element['data']['data']['VD'],
            'pin': element['data']['data']['pin'],
            'timestamp': element['data']['data']['timestamp'],
            'other': element['data']['data']['other'],
            'CDP': element['data']['data']['CDP'],
            'dir': element['data']['data']['dir'],
            'attr1' : element['data']['data']['attr1'],
            'seo' : element['data']['data']['seo'],
            'day' : element['data']['data']['day'],
            'DP' : element['data']['data']['DP'],
            'at' : element['data']['data']['at'],
            }]
```

The issue happens since you need to send a Key Value array to BigQuery, and you were sending a JSON dictionary with unicode strings.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Create a table with column names same as the key of the dictionary of your pipeline you want to insert.

For example:

```
output2 = output|beam.io.WriteToBigQuery('gcpcloud1-254210:dataflow.dataflow')
```

my output pipeline is a dictionary `{'age': 30, 'city': 'New York', 'name': 'John'}`

that I want to insert. So my table has a schema `{age:INTEGER,name:STRING,city:STRING}`

```
input = (p | beam.io.ReadFromText('gs://bucketname/*.json'))
output=(input|beam.Map(lambda e : json.loads(e))
beam.io.WriteToBigQuery('projectid:dataset.table'))
```